# What is a right way of creating RecyclerView with loading images?

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create a RecyclerView with fragments that download images from server, but i faced some problems:
When scrolling to fast, you can see previous pictures, i dont really want this. And the second thing is that i have some OOM crashing i dont really know what to do with, can some more experienced programmers help me?

My fragment adapter code:

```
public class MyPliksAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <MyPliksAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<MyPlikClass> myPliksList = Collections.emptyList();
VolleySingleton volleySingleton;
ImageLoader imageLoader;

public MyPliksAdapter (Context context, List<MyPlikClass> myPliks) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    myPliksList =myPliks;

    volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getsInstance();

    imageLoader = volleySingleton.getImageLoader();

}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_pliks_single,parent,false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final MyPlikClass currentItem = myPliksList.get(position);


    //TODO:
    if (currentItem.myPlikUserFromImgUrl != null ){

        imageLoader.get(currentItem.myPlikUserFromImgUrl, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer imageContainer, boolean b) {

                holder.myPlikUserFromImg.setImageBitmap(imageContainer.getBitmap());
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

            }
        });
    }

    if (currentItem.myPlikPhotoUrl != null){

        holder.myPlikPhoto.setImageUrl(currentItem.myPlikPhotoUrl,imageLoader );
       //(, "Wrong sesion, pls relogin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    //holder.myPlikGetDate.setText(currentItem.myPlikGetDate);

    byte[] titleData = Base64.decode(currentItem.myPlikTitle, Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] descriptionData = Base64.decode(currentItem.myPlikDescription, Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] nameData = Base64.decode(currentItem.myPlikUserFromName, Base64.DEFAULT);

    //byte[] data = Base64.decode(currentItem.myPlikTitle, Base64.DEFAULT);
    String title = null;
    String name = null;
    String description = null;

    try {
        title = new String(titleData, "UTF-8");
        name = new String(nameData, "UTF-8");
        description = new String(descriptionData, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(description != null && !description.isEmpty()) {
        holder.myPlikDeskription.setText(description);
        holder.descriptionLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    holder.myPlikTitle.setText(title);
    holder.myPlikUserFromName.setText(name);
    holder.myPlikUserFromNickname.setText(currentItem.myPlikUserFromNickname);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return myPliksList.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    NetworkImageView myPlikPhoto;
    ImageView myPlikUserFromImg;
    TextView myPlikUserFromName;
    ImageView myPlikDeskriptionIcon;
    TextView myPlikDeskription;
    TextView myPlikUserFromNickname;
    //TextView myPlikGetDate;

    TextView myPlikTitle;
    RelativeLayout descriptionLayout;
    //RecyclerView recyclerView;
    //GalleryAdapter adapter;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        myPlikTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.myPlikTitle);
        myPlikUserFromName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.myPlikUserFromName);
        myPlikUserFromNickname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.myPlikUserFromNickname);
        myPlikUserFromImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.myPlikUserFromImg);
        myPlikPhoto = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_plick_content_img);
        myPlikDeskription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_plick_content_description);
        myPlikDeskriptionIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_plik_content_comment_icon);
        descriptionLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.descripdion_block);

        //adapter = new GalleryAdapter(inflater.getContext(), getImgIds());
        //recyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.galleryList);

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is very complicated, so I recommend to use `Picasso`(http://square.github.io/picasso/) to handle image problems. It handles ImageView recycling and download cancelation in an adapter.

And there is also an official guide on how to handle concurrency problems when loading images in a list: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html. This solution, which is based on `AsyncTask`, works too.

For OOM problems, try to downsample the images before they are loaded in memory. Check this: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html